# Get the latest Y value

Tags: javascript

Can anyone guide me on how to get the latest Y value. Below is the working code that I have tried, but does not return the latest Y. Thank you.

When Y is null ->
1)My requirement is to use the latest Y value, if the timestamp is no more than 10 seconds old.
2) If the timestamp is older than 10 sec. I show '*'.

```
// I get previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp as below   
var dateTime = new Date(timestamp);
dateTime.setSeconds(dateTime.getSeconds() - 10);
var previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp  = dateTime.getTime() 

// Get Y data, if it falls between previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp and timestamp. 
let data = s.groupedData.find(el => el.x >= previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp ) && s.groupedData.find(el => el.x <= timestamp) 

// If data is not null, I retrieve 'data.y'. If not '*'.
let res = (data != null) ? Data.y: "*";
return res;
```

Data structure as below:

```
[
  { "x": 1694192563868, "Y":1},
  { "x": 1694192563874, "Y":3 },
  { "x": 1694192563888, "Y":8 },
  { "x": 1694192563892, "Y":4 }
]
```

Comment: Please share the data

Comment: Please update this code to follow JS conventions. Use `let` or `const` for mutable/immutable variables, and tag all your variables, no bare assignments like that `Data` or `Res`. Also, follow naming conventions: only classes start with a capital. As for your question: you're not showing a function, this code doesn't have a return, so start there, so that folks can even comment on how you could store previous values because they now know what actual code flow you implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 2 main issues lie in how your setting datetime which is a mutable value that will always be equal to previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp and how you're executing the find across the array with an unintentional short circuit via the && joining the two results.

I think the following should help you get the results your looking for.

```js
let dateTime = new Date();
const present = new Date();

dateTime.setSeconds(dateTime.getSeconds() - 10);
const previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp  = dateTime.getTime() 


// Get Y data, if it falls between previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp and timestamp. 
// the below is incorrect due to how && handles two 'truthy' entities. it will return the second if its present, you should use the uncommentted line instead
// const Data = s.groupedData.find(el => el.x >= previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp ) && s.groupedData.find(el => el.x <= dateTime) 

const Data = s.groupedData.find(el => el.x >= previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp && el.x < present) 

// If data is not null, I retrieve 'Data.y'. If not '*'.
const Res = Data ? Data.y: "*";
```

ps: i added some randomized boiler plate so you can try it yourself and let me know if there's still any issues

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }
  
// Note  getRandomInt(1.99) returns either zero or one exclusively
function getRandomTimeOffset(max){
    const dateTime = new Date(); // generate the current timestamp
    dateTime.setSeconds(    // manipulate current time stamp to produce some dummy data
            dateTime.getSeconds() + ( ( -1 * getRandomInt(1.99) ) * getRandomInt(max)) // randomly add or subract time to the data
            )
    return dateTime
}

const s = {
    groupedData : Array.from({length: 100}, () => 
    {
        return {
         x:  getRandomTimeOffset(10),
         y:  'dummy data'
        }
    })
}
      
let dateTime = new Date();
const present = new Date();

dateTime.setSeconds(dateTime.getSeconds() - 10);
const previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp  = dateTime.getTime() 


// Get Y data, if it falls between previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp and timestamp. 
// the below is incorrect due to how && handles two 'truthy' entities. it will return the second if its present, you should use the uncommentted line instead
// const Data = s.groupedData.find(el => el.x >= previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp ) && s.groupedData.find(el => el.x <= dateTime) 

const Data = s.groupedData.find(el => el.x >= previousTenSecondsFromTimestamp && el.x < present) 

// If data is not null, I retrieve 'Data.y'. If not '*'.
const Res = Data ? Data.y: "*";
      
console.log(s)
console.log(present)
console.log(Data)
console.log(Res)
```